# File fails to upload to google drive from tablet

Tags: google-drive, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have a galaxy Tab 3 with some pictures on it I'd like to upload to Google Drive. Whenever I go into gallery and select them it just keeps working at 0.0Kb and then says "upload fail". Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?